# How to replace a float written as a string if greater or less than?

Tags: regex, vim, awk, scripting

I have an image written in a text format and I need to set pixel which are near black to black and those which are near white as white.

The file use the [ʜꜱʟ colour space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and looks like this :

```
0,0: (19.2529%,100%,22.7451%)  #31FF3A  hsl(19.2529%,100%,22.7451%)
1,0: (18.5185%,98.1818%,21.5686%)  #2FFA37  hsl(18.5185%,98.1818%,21.5686%)
2,0: (18.4524%,90.3226%,24.3137%)  #2FE63E  hsl(18.4524%,90.3226%,24.3137%)
3,0: (18.661%,100%,22.9412%)  #30FF3B  hsl(18.661%,100%,22.9412%)
4,0: (18.9891%,100%,23.9216%)  #30FF3D  hsl(18.9891%,100%,23.9216%)
5,0: (18.9076%,100%,23.3333%)  #30FF3C  hsl(18.9076%,100%,23.3333%)
6,0: (18.7107%,86.8852%,23.9216%)  #30DE3D  hsl(18.7107%,86.8852%,23.9216%)
7,0: (18.6275%,92.7273%,21.5686%)  #30EC37  hsl(18.6275%,92.7273%,21.5686%)
8,0: (19.2192%,100%,21.7647%)  #31FF38  hsl(19.2192%,100%,21.7647%)
9,0: (19.2529%,100%,22.7451%)  #31FF3A  hsl(19.2529%,100%,22.7451%)
10,0: (19.1667%,100%,23.5294%)  #31FF3C  hsl(19.1667%,100%,23.5294%)
11,0: (19.209%,96.7213%,23.9216%)  #31F73D  hsl(19.209%,96.7213%,23.9216%)
12,0: (18.7302%,84%,24.5098%)  #30D63F  hsl(18.7302%,84%,24.5098%)
13,0: (18.6275%,85%,23.5294%)  #30D93C  hsl(18.6275%,85%,23.5294%)
14,0: (18.6728%,93.1034%,22.7451%)  #30ED3A  hsl(18.6728%,93.1034%,22.7451%)
15,0: (18.7316%,100%,22.1569%)  #30FF39  hsl(18.7316%,100%,22.1569%)
16,0: (18.5841%,100%,22.1569%)  #2FFF39  hsl(18.5841%,100%,22.1569%)
17,0: (18.6186%,100%,21.7647%)  #2FFF38  hsl(18.6186%,100%,21.7647%)
18,0: (18.6186%,100%,21.7647%)  #2FFF38  hsl(18.6186%,100%,21.7647%)
19,0: (18.5841%,100%,22.1569%)  #2FFF39  hsl(18.5841%,100%,22.1569%)
20,0: (18.5345%,100%,22.7451%)  #2FFF3A  hsl(18.5345%,100%,22.7451%)
21,0: (18.5345%,96.6667%,23.5294%)  #2FF73C  hsl(18.5345%,96.6667%,23.5294%)
22,0: (18.5345%,98.3051%,23.1373%)  #2FFB3B  hsl(18.5345%,98.3051%,23.1373%)
23,0: (18.5507%,100%,22.549%)  #2FFF3A  hsl(18.5507%,100%,22.549%)
24,0: (18.5507%,100%,22.549%)  #2FFF3A  hsl(18.5507%,100%,22.549%)
25,0: (18.5345%,98.3051%,23.1373%)  #2FFB3B  hsl(18.5345%,98.3051%,23.1373%)
26,0: (18.5345%,98.3051%,23.1373%)  #2FFB3B  hsl(18.5345%,98.3051%,23.1373%)
27,0: (18.5345%,100%,22.7451%)  #2FFF3A  hsl(18.5345%,100%,22.7451%)
28,0: (18.5673%,100%,22.3529%)  #2FFF39  hsl(18.5673%,100%,22.3529%)
29,0: (18.5841%,100%,22.1569%)  #2FFF39  hsl(18.5841%,100%,22.1569%)
30,0: (18.5673%,100%,22.3529%)  #2FFF39  hsl(18.5673%,100%,22.3529%)
31,0: (18.5507%,100%,22.549%)  #2FFF3A  hsl(18.5507%,100%,22.549%)
32,0: (18.8218%,100%,22.7451%)  #30FF3A  hsl(18.8218%,100%,22.7451%)
33,0: (18.7316%,100%,22.1569%)  #30FF39  hsl(18.7316%,100%,22.1569%)
34,0: (18.7302%,84%,24.5098%)  #30D63F  hsl(18.7302%,84%,24.5098%)
35,0: (18.5824%,60%,28.4314%)  #2F9949  hsl(18.5824%,60%,28.4314%)
```

So how I *(for example)* can replace the values above *(except the first 2 numbers (`x,x:`) which give the pixel coordinate)* by`(0%,0%,0%)  #000000  hsl(0%,0%,0%)`using vim or awk or with an another scripting tool?

I’m thinking using the light/last part of ʜꜱʟ values for determining if the line *(except`[0−9],[0−9]:`)* need to be replaced, but I have no idea on how to do this.

Comment: You need to define what "near" black and "near" white mean. Is it just that the L value is below or above 50%, respectively? And you haven't shown what you want your white replacement to look like.

Comment: @ooga : Like I said in my newest edit is I am thinking to using the light value.  And typically below or above 25% 75% respectively. But this touch a broader issue as some pixel may be part of letters anti aliasing and setting them black would change letters shape *(so they should be set to white and letters bodies to dark.)*. Using the light value would still be a minor workaround.

Comment: While it is certainly *possible* to do it in Vim or awk, it would be easier in a bit friendlier language like Ruby or Perl. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: The first and last part seem to be same; the hex seems to be independent of those (or I can't convert properly, which is also possible). What exactly do you want to change? Both hsl colours? Only the second hsl colour, that is actually labeled as `hsl(...)`? All three colours, hex included (in which case, I need to see that the conversion is correct)? All three colours independently from each other?

Comment: @Amadan : yes if course.

Comment: @Amadan : the first part and last parts are both in HSL format. I know changing those two is required. But I don’t know for the hex colour value. So it would be better to update all three members

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        black="(0%,0%,0%)  #000000  hsl(0%,0%,0%)"
        white="(0%,0%,100%)  #FFFFFF  hsl(0%,0%,100%)"
    }
    {
        line=$0
        coords=$1
        FS=","
        $0=$0
        match($4, "%")
        sub("%.*", "", $4)
        if ($4 < 25)
            printf("%s %s\n", coords, black)
        else if ($4 > 75)
            printf("%s %s\n", coords, white)
        else print line
        FS=" "
    }
' <img.txt
```

Comment: It converts all existing white values to black.